# GNU Screen: Multiuser Synchronized Screen Switching

Tags: gnu, gnu-screen

I am running GNU Screen in multiuser mode and have several users connected to the same instance. I was wondering how I can synchronize screen/tab switching between all users.

For example, if I do "ctrl-a 3" I would want all connected users to switch to tab 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Solution:

```
ctrl-a :at % select n
```

(where n is the screen number)